# MPLAB harmony v3 'sys_time'

Tags: ethernet, debugging, mplab

[image]

hi, i am trying to debugging a ethernet PHY chip using MPLAB harmony v3. (My controller board is SAM E54 curiosity ultra.)
However, I got a SYS_TIME pink circle in MHC like above picture.

How can i change green one?

I found 'MPLAB harmony v3 application development' document, it says to add the time system service module as shown below. but i don't know what it means.

[image]

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Harmony is a beast to use and learn, so I can understand the confusion.

Typically, when you insert a block into the project graph, there may be inputs and outputs associated with that block.  For some of them you get to connect manually, for example, the SYS_CONSOLE yellow diamond requires an external connection you have to make manually, probably to a UART driver.  The circles inside the block indicate the requirement for a matching component that needs to be in the graph.  Notice how NETCONFIG is green, meaning that you have already added a component that meets that dependency.

So to your question specifically, you have not added a module to address the SYS_TIME dependency.  I work mostly with PIC32 chips so not sure if the modules are different for the SAM board (or what chip it uses) but you may need to add the Time System Service module (or equivalent) to address the dependency.

Update - I don't have a TCPIP CORE on my system but I can include an SPI SD Card driver which also requires time.  Here is what it looks like after I added it to the project graph:

[image]

In my case, it actually asked me if it should also add the Time service, which would address the dependency, I said no to demonstrate.  So now it also has the red circle.  This is what the window with available components looks like:

[image]

You just have to add the TIME system service, located under "Harmony->SystemServices".  Below is what it looks like after I added that component.

[image]

Note how the SYS_TIME is now green, meaning its dependency has been met.

Comment: Yiannis, thank you for your answer!

Then you means, i have to add extension board(time system service module) on controller board?

Comment: You should not have to change the hardware, this is a software issue.  I'm updating the answer as I can't include graphics in a comment.

Comment: I solved the problem!! I learned a lot about MPLAB configurator on this opportunity!
Thanks for your kind reply! Have a nice day

Comment: Glad to hear; you may consider upvoting/accepting the answer as that is the appropriate way in this site to acknowledge helpful answers.

Comment: I think I'm upvoting/accepting your answer! thanks!